# How can I fix a completely random CSS glitch problem on mobile browsers only?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website that I have developed: [Mychordbook](https://www.mychordbook.com), it is an instrument learning website.

I have a strange GUI problem that I could not figure out for months. When you open the website from your mobile browser, chrome or safari (this problem does not exist on desktop). As the instrument is playing automatically or you click on the instrument to play the chord, strings on guitar/ukulele has white glitches, completely random (I could not figure out after which action it exactly happens). I have tried many things with CSS properties position or z-index. Nothing worked. Strangely, this glitch sometimes reveals the text beneath the instrument, although nothing is transparent there.

Just to give some ideas, here is the animation code for strings playing:

```
function play_string(inst, string){
...

    // display red string
    var string_played = $instruments[inst].$strings[string-1]
        string_played.classList.remove('transition')
        string_played.classList.add('playing')
    setTimeout(()=>{ string_played.classList.add('transition')}, 100);
    setTimeout(()=>{ string_played.classList.remove('playing')}, 200);
    //display pick
    var pick_played = $instruments[inst].$picks[string - 1]
    pick_played.classList.remove('transition')
    pick_played.classList.add('playing')
    setTimeout(()=>{ pick_played.classList.add('transition')}, 100);
    setTimeout(()=>{ pick_played.classList.remove('playing')}, 200);
}
...
```

I can also provide any code if anybody has any idea, since the codebase is really huge.

I have also recorded a video of the problem here:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jcsxrPdp0lY

Some related CSS (You can go to check all other CSS from Mychordbook.com in any song page):

```
...
.guitar .string {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1;
}
.guitar .string.active {
  background-color: white;
}
.guitar .string[data-string='1'] {
  top: 8.333%;
  margin-top: -0.5px;
  height: 1px;
}
.guitar .string[data-string='2'] {
  top: 25%;
  margin-top: -0.5px;
  height: 1px;
}
...
```

Lastly, I have seen this problem on my Iphone X (14.0.1 Safari) and Chrome 86.0.4240.77. I have also tried it on Andriod on which there is no problem. And strangely, not all Iphones also have this problem. I start to suspect this bug might not be about my code. I am open to any ides.

Comment: Please add screenshots of the issue and css code as well

Comment: What you do actually mean by "white glitches"?  Are images being displayed with white backgrounds, for example?

Comment: I have updated the post.

Comment: your website looks awesome to me. will you give the page url so that we know adjactly and it would be better if you also post the screenshots of the problem

Comment: moreover the css has its own rendering limitations that why people came up with the idea of canvas. so i recommend that you migrate your css concept to canvas or use some libraries like threejs